# Adding IDs based on groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to find a solution using `tidyverse` syntax to solve the following issue.

Given a table of video frame types and sizes, I'd like to group them into "Groups of Pictures". A GOP starts whenever an I-frame occurs. So, given this data:

```
d.test <- tribble(
  ~frame_type, ~frame_size,
  "I", 960,
  "B", 23,
  "P", 48,
  "B", 58,
  "I", 501,
  "B", 23,
  "P", 48,
  "B", 58
)
```

I would like the first four frames to belong to group 1, the next four to group 2, etc. Groups can be of different lengths, so just using a trick with modulo four is not enough.

I first tried this:

```
d.test %>% 
    mutate(group = group_indices(., frame_type))
```

… but it repeats the group index over the entire dataframe.

I also tried the `my_rleid` function [suggested here](http://my_rleid%20%3C-%20function(x)%20%7B%20%20%201L%20+%20cumsum(dplyr::coalesce(x%20!=%20dplyr::lag(x),%20FALSE))%20%7D):

```
my_rleid <- function(x) {
  1L + cumsum(dplyr::coalesce(x != dplyr::lag(x), FALSE))
}
```

… but this includes all frame types, so returns group IDs of 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it working by calculating the cumulative sum of a comparison of the frame type against `I`:

```
d.test %>% 
  mutate(group = cumsum(frame_type == "I"))
```

This returns:

```
  frame_type frame_size group
  <chr>           <dbl> <int>
1 I                 960     1
2 B                  23     1
3 P                  48     1
4 B                  58     1
5 I                 501     2
6 B                  23     2
7 P                  48     2
8 B                  58     2
```

Comment: no need for `if_else`. You can just do `cumsum(frame_type == 'I')`. It works the same way on logical as well.

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion!